# Redirect to previous page with params attached

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a review page for schools that i link to like this;

```
<%= school_reviews_path(school_id: @school.id) %>
```

Generating a link like this;

```
http://address.com/school_reviews?school_id=1
```

However, under the reviews is a form that create a new review posting it `create` action of `schools_reviews controller`

However, after creation of the review i want to rerender the page with the accompanying parameters i.e `school_id=1`

I have tried several methods like this but it aint working instead it redirects to `http://address.com/school_reviews` without the params meanig we do not fetch the right information.

```
def create
    @review = SchoolReview.new(params[:review])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @review.save        
        format.html { redirect_to school_reviews_path(:school_id => @review.school_id) }
        format.json { head :no_content }  
      else
        format.html { redirect_to school_reviews_path(:school_id => @review.school_id) }
        format.json { head :no_content }  
      end
    end
  end
```

Any ideas, will be greatful.

Comment: Define *it ain't working*. What happens, then? While not idiomatic, as you should be using nested routes, it looks correct.

Comment: @MaurícioLinhares, i have improved the question.

Comment: Agree with the above.  You will save yourself a LOT of angst if you go in a more RESTful direction like Rails kind of pushes you towards.  You probably want a URL more like /schools/1/reviews.  The form for creating a new review would POST to /schools/1/reviews/create, then a save would redirect back to /schools/1/reviews -- all of which would happen without any code overrides necessary by following the nested resource pattern.  Hope that helps.  More info: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that your form, most likely, isn't setting the school id anywhere, so let's make your code be more like what it should be, first setup routes like this:

```
resources :schools do 
  resources :school_reviews
end
```

Your controller name doesn't change, but the implementation will change to be as follows:

```
class SchoolReviewsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :load_school

  def create
    @review = @school.school_reviews.build(params[:review])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @review.save        
        format.html { redirect_to school_school_reviews_path(@school) }
        format.json { head :no_content }  
      else
        format.html { redirect_to school_school_reviews_path(@school) }
        format.json { head :no_content }  
      end
    end
  end

  protected 

  def load_school
    @school = School.find(params[:school_id])
  end

end
```

You will also have to change the `form_for` call at your view to something like:

```
<%= form_for( [@school, @review] ) do |f| %>
    Your form content here.
<% end %>
```

Your link will change as well to:

```
<%= school_school_reviews_path(@school) %>
```

You might also want to change the `SchoolReview` model just to `Review` to remove the `school_school_` from the URLs.

And, as usual, read the documentation on [routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) to understand what's going on.